How to show user dashboard after login through google login by using passport google oauth 2?
For login as usually done through react express controller and routes like below code
import { comparePassword, hashPassword } from "../helper/authHelper.js";
import userModel from "../models/userModel.js";
import orderModel from "../models/orderModel.js";
import JWT from "jsonwebtoken";

export const registerCotroller = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { name, mobile, email, password, city, answer } = req.body;
    if (!name) {
      return res.send({ message: "email is required" });
    }
    if (!mobile) {
      return res.send({ message: "mobile is required" });
    }
    if (!email) {
      return res.send({ message: "email is required" });
    }
    if (!password) {
      return res.send({ message: "password is required" });
    }

    if (!city) {
      return res.send({ message: "city is required" });
    }
    if (!answer) {
      return res.send({ message: "answer is reuired" });
    }
    //chaeck user by email
    const existUser = await userModel.findOne({ email });
    if (existUser) {
      return res.send({
        success: false,
        message: "user already registered ,kindly login",
      });
    }

    //register user
    const hashedPassword = await hashPassword(password);
    const user = await new userModel({
      name,
      mobile,
      email,
      password: hashedPassword,
      city,
      answer,
    }).save();

    res.status(201).send({
      success: true,
      message: "user registered succesfully",
      user,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(500).send({
      success: false,
      message: "error in registration",
      error,
    });
  }
};

export const loginController = async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { email, password } = req.body;
    if (!email || !password) {
      return res.status(400).send({
        success: false,
        message: "either email or password is required",
      });
    }

    const user = await userModel.findOne({ email });
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(401).send({
        success: false,
        message: "email is not registered with us kindly register first",
      });
    }
    const match = await comparePassword(password, user.password);
    if (!match) {
      return res.status(402).send({
        success: false,
        message: "wrong password or email kindly enter right one",
      });
    }
    //gen token

    const token = await JWT.sign({ _id: user._id }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, {
      expiresIn: "7 d",
    });
    res.status(200).send({
      success: true,
      message: "Login Succesfuly",
      user: {
        _id: user._id,
        name: user.name,
        mobile: user.mobile,
        email: user.email,
        city: user.city,
        role: user.role,
        answer: user.answer,
      },
      token,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
    res.status(503).send({
      success: false,
      message: "error in login",
      error,
    });
  }
};

And react UI is as :
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Layout from "../components/Layout/Layout";
import axios from "axios";
import { useNavigate, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import toast from "react-hot-toast";
import { useAuth } from "../components/context/authContext";
//import GoogleLogin from "react-google-login";

const Login = () => {
  const [email, setEmail] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [auth, setAuth] = useAuth();
  const location = useLocation();
  const [user, setUser] = useState("");

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const respo = await axios.post("/api/pp/auth/login", { email, password });
      if (respo && respo.data.success) {
        toast.success(respo.data.message);
        setAuth({
          ...auth,
          user: respo.data.user,
          token: respo.data.token,
        });
        localStorage.setItem("auth", JSON.stringify(respo.data));
        navigate(location.state || "/");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      toast.error("something went wrong");
    }
  };
  useEffect(() => {
    const loggedInUser = localStorage.getItem("auth");
    if (loggedInUser) {
      setUser(loggedInUser);
      navigate("/dashboard/admin");
    }
  }, [auth?.token]);

  const loginwithgoogle = () => {
    window.open("http://localhost:8000/auth/google/callback", "_self");
  };
  //const responseSuccessGoogle = (response) => { console.log(response)};

  //const responseFailureGoogle = (response) => {};

  return (
    <Layout>
      <div className="login">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div className="mb-3">
            <label htmlFor="exampleInputEmail1" className="form-label">
              Email address
            </label>
            <input
              type="email"
              value={email}
              onChange={(e) => setEmail(e.target.value)}
              className="form-control"
              id="exampleInputEmail1"
              aria-describedby="emailHelp"
              required
            />
          </div>
          <div className="mb-3">
            <label htmlFor="exampleInputPassword1" className="form-label">
              Password
            </label>
            <input
              type="password"
              value={password}
              onChange={(e) => setPassword(e.target.value)}
              className="form-control"
              id="exampleInputPassword1"
              required
            />
          </div>
          <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary">
            Submit
          </button>
          &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;
          <button
            type="submit"
            onClick={() => navigate("/forgot-password")}
            className="btn btn-danger"
          >
            Forgot Password
          </button>
        </form>
            <button
          className="login-with-google-btn btn btn-success m-3"
          onClick={loginwithgoogle}
        >
          Login with Google
        </button>
      </div>
    </Layout>
  );
};

export default Login;

//server .js file in which google login function exist 
import express from "express";
import colors from "colors";
import connectDB from "./config/db.js";
import morgan from "morgan";
import authRoute from "./routes/authRoute.js";
import cors from "cors";
import categoryRoute from "./routes/categoryRoute.js";
import productRoute from "./routes/productRoute.js";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import session from "express-session";
import passport from "passport";
import userdb from "./models/googleModel.js";

import { Strategy as GoogleStrategy } from "passport-google-oauth20";

connectDB();
dotenv.config();
const app = express();

//seesion create
app.use(
  session({
    secret: "gergpk5656@jfgger2455",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: true,
  })
);

//middleware
app.use(
  cors({
    origin: "http://localhost:3000",
    methods: "GET,PUT,POST,DELETE",
    credentials: true,
  })
);
//passport use
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(
  new GoogleStrategy(
    {
      clientID: process.env.googleClient,
      clientSecret: process.env.googleSecret,
      callbackURL: "/auth/google/callback",
      scope: ["profile", "email"],
    },

    async (accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) => {
      try {
        let user = await userdb.findOne({ googleId: profile.id });
        if (!user) {
          user = await userdb({
            googleId: profile.id,
            displayName: profile.displayName,
            email: profile.emails[0].value,
            image: profile.photos[0].value,
          });
          await user.save();
        }
        return done(null, user);
      } catch (error) {}
    }
  )
);

passport.serializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user);
});
passport.deserializeUser((user, done) => {
  done(null, user);
});

//initilize google
app.get(
  "/auth/google",
  passport.authenticate("google", { scope: ["profile", "email"] })
);

app.get(
  "/auth/google/callback",
  passport.authenticate("google", {
    successRedirect: "http://localhost:3000/googleUser",
    failureRedirect: "http://localhost:3000/login",
  })
);

app.use(express.json());
app.use(morgan());

//routes
app.use("/api/pp/auth", authRoute);


const port = process.env.PORT;

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`app runing on port ${port}`.bgMagenta.white);
});

How to get dashboard as I simply login in through controller and route function as it is usually happen in mern....by google login ...when I login through gmail I get logged in but dashboard is protected route which need token JWT and user, but after gmail login I have only Google Token and google User...

Welcome to StackOverflow. Read: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example. It's also a good idea to take the tour, read about what's on-topic in the help center, and How to Ask.
